# Popover more than one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

My problem is that I designed a popover for button for filter. When popover open there is filter when click button to okey filter popover close and do process. Problem start here . when i click again popover button, and okey filter, process is done for 2 times and popover close, when i do filter again popover do 3 times and close, but it must be only one for every filter. code is below;

```
console.log("girdi");
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'click',
    html: 'true',
    content: '<textarea class="popover-textarea"></textarea>',
    template: '<div class="popover"style="width:450px;height:250px;">' +
        '<div class="arrow">' +

        '</div>'+
        '<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">' +
        '<div style="width:80%;margin-top:20px;margin-left:10%;background:#eee;height:30px;border-radius:5px;border:3px solid #eee">' +
        '<a href="#" id="customDate" class="clicked" style="width:33%;height:100%;float:left;text-align:center;padding-top:3px;border-radius:3px;">Range</a>' +
        '<a href="#" id="dayChoose" class="" style="width:33%;height:100%;float:left;text-align:center;padding-top:3px;border-radius:3px;">Days</a>' +
        '<a href="#" id="phoneChoose" class="" style="width:33%;height:100%;float:left;text-align:center;padding-top:3px;border-radius:3px;">Phone</a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div style="width:80%;margin-top:20px;margin-left:10%;height:120px;">' +
        '<div style="width:100%;height:100%;display:block"class="customArea area">' +
        '<form>' +
        '<div class="radio">' +
        '<label><input class="customType" type="radio"style="color:grey" name="optradio"value="0">None</label>' +
        ' </div>' +
        '<div class="radio">'+
        '<label><input class="customType" type="radio"style="color:grey"checked="checked" name="optradio"value="1">Today</label>' +
        ' </div>' +
        '<div class="radio">' +
        ' <label><input class="customType" type="radio"style="color:grey" name="optradio"value="2">Week</label>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="radio">' +
        ' <label><input class="customType" type="radio"style="color:grey" name="optradio"value="3">Month</label>' +
        '</div>' +

        '</form>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div style="width:100%;height:100%;display:none"class="dateArea area">' +
        '<div class="input-group date">' +
        '<input type="date"class="form-control"id="dateSpe"placeholder="DD.MM.YYYY" value="">' +
        '<div class="input-group-addon">' +
        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div style="width:100%;height:100%;display:none"class="phoneArea area">' +
        '<div class="input-group date">' +
        '<input type="text"class="form-control"id="phone"placeholder="Phone" value="">' +
        '<div class="input-group-addon">' +
        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +

        '</div>' +
        '<input type="button" value="Listele"id="reportGet" style="width:100%;height:30px;background:darkcyan;border-radius:5px;color:white">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'

}).on('shown', function () {       

    console.log("girdi");
    $("#reportGet").click(function () {

        var startDate = "";
        var endDate = "";
        var phone = "";

        var customChoose = document.querySelector('input[name="optradio"]:checked').value;
        var speDate = $("#dateSpe").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();

        if (customChoose != "0" && speDate != "") {
            //alert("İki farklı tarih filtresi girilemez");
            new PNotify({
                title: "Mobil Eğitim",
                type: "warning",
                text: "İki farklı tarih filtresi girilemez",
                styling: 'bootstrap3',
                hide: true, delay: 3000,
                before_close: function (PNotify) {
                    PNotify.update({
                        title: PNotify.options.title + " - Enjoy your Stay",
                        before_close: null
                    });

                    PNotify.queueRemove();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            //$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
            return;
        }

        if (customChoose == "0" && speDate == "" && phone == "") {
            //alert("En az bir filtre girmelisiniz");
            new PNotify({
                title: "Mobil Eğitim",
                type: "warning",
                text: "En az bir filtre girmelisiniz",

                styling: 'bootstrap3',
                hide: true, delay: 3000,
                before_close: function (PNotify) {
                    PNotify.update({
                        title: PNotify.options.title + " - Enjoy your Stay",
                        before_close: null
                    });

                    PNotify.queueRemove();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            //$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
            return;
        }
        if (customChoose == "0" && speDate == "") {
            startDate = '01.01.1990';
            endDate = todayDate();
            $("#dateInput").val(phone);
        }
        if (speDate != "") {

            speDate = speDate.substring(8, 10) + "." + speDate.substring(5, 7) + "." + speDate.substring(0, 4);

            startDate = speDate
            endDate = speDate;
            $("#dateInput").val(speDate);
        }
        if (customChoose == "1") {
            startDate = todayDate();
            endDate = todayDate();
            $("#dateInput").val("@Html.Raw(Resources.Resource.value_today)");
        }
        if (customChoose == "2") {
            startDate = weekDate();
            endDate = todayDate();
            $("#dateInput").val("@Html.Raw(Resources.Resource.value_week)");
        }
        if (customChoose == "3") {
            startDate = monthDate();
            endDate = todayDate();
            $("#dateInput").val("@Html.Raw(Resources.Resource.value_month)");
        }
        getReport(startDate, endDate, phone);
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');

        return;
    });
    $("#customDate").click(function () {
        $("#customDate").addClass("clicked");
        $("#dayChoose").removeClass("clicked");
        $("#phoneChoose").removeClass("clicked");
        $(".area").hide();
        $(".customArea").show();

    });
    $("#dayChoose").click(function () {
        $("#customDate").removeClass("clicked");
        $("#dayChoose").addClass("clicked");
        $("#phoneChoose").removeClass("clicked");
        $(".area").hide();
        $(".dateArea").show();
    });
    $("#phoneChoose").click(function () {
        $("#customDate").removeClass("clicked");
        $("#dayChoose").removeClass("clicked");
        $("#phoneChoose").addClass("clicked");
        $(".area").hide();
        $(".phoneArea").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please create an [mcve] instead of all that code

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell from your code example, but i assume that you keep adding `click` event handlers to your filter every time the popover  `shown` event is triggert.